# Design decision for text message queueing implementation

Tags: java, servlets, message-queue

I have a scenario where using certain text message gateway I receive incoming messages via GET within the servlet, compose the reply message, store it in database with id key and then just send it out using corresponding service. Message sending result is coming to me via POST (message id and textual result (success or failure)).

So, what i would like to implement is message queueing: sending messages one by one with fixed numer of retries in case of failure.

I can't just get the way to implement it right. Here's what had come to me, just for example - in the message handler's doGet method I am receiving new message, composing the reply, storing the reply message to the database and then putting it into the singleton queue to send them out when it's time. Then I could have some kind of thread with run() method that just continuously in infinite loop takes messages from the queue one by one and tries to send it certain amount of times (say, 5).

If the message is sent successfully - then all I need is to remove the message from the queue and break the inner loop.

Here's the tricky part where I get stuck - how do I decide within the thread whether the message sent successfully or not if I get the result via POST in the serlvet (message id and result)?

I could store current id of the message that I try sending at the moment, but that doesn't make things clearer to me.

So what concerns me is what would be the best way to implement message queueing given my situation? 
I'm not saying that the design decision I suggested is in any way sufficient and needs to stay. I'd appreciate any help - whether it would be suggestion of improving the way I see the implementation that resolves problems I mentioned or suggesting some kind of entirely new more suitable approach, which would be really welcomed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some external means of storing the state of the message, for example, a database. The POST handler will update the database with the success or failure condition and the message queue can query the database for the status.

Comment: Thank you! That almost solves my problem, I have only one question - i suppose, I am going to need some delay before querying the database - to wait for the POST to come and for database to update, am I correct? If so, what is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: You can also store the last time the queue attempted to send the message. Everytime you check the head of the queue for whether it was received successfully, also check to see if the last time you sent the message was sent recently, if yes, relegate it to the back of the queue.